# Refusing to untap exolnet/deprecated because it contains the following installed formulae or casks:

Tags: php, macos, homebrew

I want to upgrade to PHP 8 with Homebrew on Mac. But there is a problem!

1.`php -v`

```
PHP 7.3.11 (cli) (built: Jun  5 2020 23:50:40) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.3.11, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
```

2.`brew install shivammathur/php/php@8.0`

```
Updating Homebrew...
Warning: shivammathur/php/php 8.0.3 is already installed, it's just not linked.
To link this version, run:
  brew link php
```

3.`brew link php`

```
Error: Formulae found in multiple taps:
       * shivammathur/php/php@5.6
       * exolnet/deprecated/php@5.6

Please use the fully-qualified name (e.g. shivammathur/php/php@5.6) to refer to the formula.
```

4.`brew untap exolnet/deprecated`

```
Error: Refusing to untap exolnet/deprecated because it contains the following installed formulae or casks:
php@5.6
```

Nothing seems to work. I need to upgrade to PHP8. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you don't need php 5.6 anymore, just uninstall it and then try to untap exolnet... I had the same issue but I didn't have php 5.6 installed so I could just untap it....

Answer (score 3):

For me it worked to first uninstall then untap.

```
brew uninstall name_of_formula
brew untap cask_name/name_of_formula
```

Answer (score 2):

I was also facing this issue. I have upgraded my macOS to BigSur and started to facing the issue of to unlink the PHP version.

So problem was that, I have installed the two repo one is from the old version which was **exolnet** and in new version I have also installed shivammathur repo. So when I tried to switch the version the system got confused to which repo he should use. So, I untap the exolnet by brew untap exolnet/deprecated

Answer (score 1):

To remove `exolnet/deprecated`:

```sh
HOMEBREW_DEVELOPER=1 brew untap exolnet/deprecated
```

Then try linking the PHP version again.